How to Handle Sanctum Error in Laravel 11
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AuthController::class, 'login']);

    Route::middleware('auth:admin_sanctum')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    });
});


auth.php -
   'guards' => [
        'sanctum' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'user_sanctum' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin_sanctum' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],

then how to handle unauthencated error and valid token error for seprate guard?
I create the guard for admin & frontend and api. So i want the different guard return different error response when the token is invalid or user not authencated.
